# Visualize a image bar with a value range from 0 to 1 and back to 0 in Unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I increase a value from 0 to 1 and decrease it back to 0.

```
private Image cycleBar;
private float currentTime = 0;
private float cycleDuration = 5;

private void Start()
{
    cycleBar = GetComponent<Image>();
    UpdateCycleBar();
}

private void Update() // TimeHandler
{
    currentTime = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 1 / cycleDuration, 1); // handle the time
    UpdateCycleBar();
}

private void UpdateCycleBar()
{
    // the missing part
}
```

So now the value got its logic. How can I visualize it like this example here

[image]

When reaching the value 1, the bar has to move on to the right "zero number". After that it just resets on the left side again.

Comment: Is it imperative you do 0-1-0? I would suggest doing 0-.5-1 or 0-1-2.

Comment: well by code, it is important to have a value from 0 to 1 and back to 0. When using the UI, I could go with -1 to 0 to 1 too.

Comment: I think you need to add more parentheses to force order of operations if you want Time.time * (1 / cycleDuration). Or you could just drop the * 1 all together. Since that would be the same as Time.time / cycleDuration

Comment: I will try out some possible ways :)

Comment: i answer him in his previous post... and already i don't understand how to handle this with PingPong... :P

Comment: @Programmer just a increasing bar, it increases and resets when reaching the maximum

Comment: Well ... this is the second 0 :/ I hope the attached image can describe what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach. But don't forget to call `Initialize(float value, TimeMod mod)` method if you want initialize it from Dusk for example.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CycleBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Image cycleBar;

    private TimeMod currentMod = TimeMod.AM;

    public void Initialize(float value, TimeMod mod)
    {
        currentMod = mod;
        cycleBar.fillAmount = GetProgressbarValue(value);
    }

    public void UpdateValue(float value)
    {
        CheckTimeMod(value);
        cycleBar.fillAmount = GetProgressbarValue(value);
    }

    private void CheckTimeMod(float value)
    {
        if (Mathf.Abs(value - 1) < 0.01f)
        {
            currentMod = TimeMod.PM;
        }

        if (Mathf.Abs(value) < 0.01f)
        {
            currentMod = TimeMod.AM;
        }
    }

    private float GetProgressbarValue(float value)
    {
        switch (currentMod)
        {
            case TimeMod.AM:
                return value / 2;
            case TimeMod.PM:
                return 0.5f + Mathf.Abs(value-1) / 2;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("currentMod", currentMod, null);
        }
    }

    public enum TimeMod
    {
        AM,
        PM
    }
}
```

And controller:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private CycleBar cycleBar;

    private void Update() // TimeHandler
    {
        var value = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1); // handle the time
        cycleBar.UpdateValue(value);
    }
}
```

But if it possible, use more simple way with the range `[-1;1]`. For example you can use Slider from UnityEngine.UI

[image]

If it helps you, mark please this post as Correct Answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new image in UI, then on 2D resize mode, resize it to your complete state. now you can scale X from zero to 1 in your code.